# My login page won't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

So i'm trying to make a basic website where you can sign up and login and all that. Signing up is fine, it saves the records in the database, and logging in is fine if you have the correct username and password. If you don't fill out all fields, it takes you back to the loginform.php page and says "Login failed!". This works as well, it's fine. However, if you don't put in the correct information, it's supposed to just simply echo "Incorrect!". For some reason, instead of echoing what I tell it to, it just goes to a blank white page. This is the code for the login form:

```
<?php
   echo include("php_includes/header.php");
?>

<h3 class="first">Member Login</h3>         
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="login.php">
<strong></strong><br>
Username: <input name="username" type="text" id="username" /><br><br>
Password: <input name="password" type="password" id="password" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login" /></form><br>
<a href='register.php'>Register</a>

<?php echo include("php_includes/footer.php");?>
```

This is the code for the actual login process:

```
<?php

session_start();
include ("db_connect.php");

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

if($username && $password)
{
    $password = md5($password);
    $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget) or die(mysql_error());
    if($numrows != 0) {//if they can find it in the database
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //starts the session
    header("Location: members.php"); //log in
    } else {
       echo "Incorrect!";
    }
 } else {
    echo "Login failed!";
    include("loginform.php");
 }
```

Comment: Blank white page usually means a server error. Check your server logs

Comment: You usually don't echo an `include` file, and it doesn't need to be in parentheses.

Comment: I smell SQL injection here...

Comment: You have `action="login.php"` and `include("loginform.php");` probably the reason (page name mismatch). Plus, is `session_start();` inside ALL your pages?

Comment: BTW, you can't assume `$_POST['username']` or password are set and assign them to a variable, you have to check if they are set first cos this will produce an error!

Comment: You may need to do some better error checking and change `if($username && $password)` to `if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['username']))` while making sure that both your input fields are appropriately named `<input type="text" name="username">` and `<input type="password" name="password">`

Comment: Plus a word of advice, do NOT store passwords using `md5` and your code is wide open for injection. Good luck, my work is done here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("db_connect.php");

$errors = [];

// Assigning the variables
if ( isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) ) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
} else {
  $errors[] = "Username cannot be blank <br />";
}

if ( isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
  $password = $_POST['password'];
} else {
  $errors[] = "Password cannot be blank <br />";
}

if( isset($username) && isset($password) )
{
  $password = sha1($password);
  $queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($queryget) or die(mysql_error());
  if($numrows != 0) {//if they can find it in the database
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username; //starts the session
    header("Location: members.php"); //log in
    exit;
  } else {
    $error[] = 'Incorrect Username or password';
  }
} else {
  foreach ($errors as $error) {
    echo $error . "<br />";
  } 
}
```

Hope this helps.